# How to relax Google Caja HTML Sanitizer? It's sanitizing too much

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xss, google-caja

I am using Google Caja HTML Sanitizer (https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer), however it is sanitizing things I don't want it to.

Sometimes I want to input data in a format similar to:

```
Bob <Carpenter>
```

but this becomes:

```
Bob
```

Comment: Can  you not just use the HTMLEntities form of the < and > ?  &lt; &gt;

Answer (score 3):

Caja sanitizes HTML. `<Carpenter>` isn't valid HTML. Therefore, it gets sanitized.

If the data you're inputting isn't actually HTML, don't run it through Caja.